# extract user id and 1st inital last name from output

Tags: text-processing, sed, getent

Getting the output of user identity with getent passwd.

How can i change the output from

`u12345:John Doe`
to
`u12345,jdoe`

i got it with sed but it it removes u12345 but does give me jdoe

Comment: _What_ gives you `jdoe`?

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`, assuming `:` and space can be reliably used as field separators:

```bash
$ echo 'u12345:John Doe' | awk -F'[: ]' '{print $1 "," tolower(substr($2, 1, 1) $3)}'
u12345,jdoe
```

Comment: Good spot, thanks! I've edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

With `Perl`:

```
perl -lne 'print "$1," . lc $2 . $3 if /^([^:]+):(\w)\S+\s+(\S+)/' file
```

```
u12345,jdoe
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -nE 's/^([^:]*):([^:[:space:]])[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]+([^:[:space:]]+).*$/\1,\L\2\3/p'
```

Or use `perl`:

```
perl -C -F: -lae 'print "$F[0]," . lc("$1$2") if $F[1] =~ /^(\S)\S*\s+(\S+)/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'put "$0,{($1,$2).join.lc}" if m/^ (<-[:]>+) \: (\S) \S* \s (\S+)/;' <<< 'u12345:John Doe'
```

Sample Output:

```
u12345,jdoe
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl family. Above, Raku code is run with the `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flags. A regex matcher `m/ ... /` is used to identify lines of interest. If (`if`) there's a match, zero-indexed groups captured with `( ... )` parentheses are out`put`. Curly-braces indicate Raku code is run within (to `join` and `lc` lowercase letters).

The `$0` capture contains characters starting from the beginning of the line that *do not* contain a `:` colon. In other words, the two consecutive regex atoms `<-[:]> \:` mean *"create a custom character class that does not include colon, and look for one-or-more such characters followed by a `\:` colon.*"

The regex atoms `(\S) \S+ \s (\S+)` mean _"capture a `\S` non-whitespace character into `$1` (i.e. first-name initial); identify one-or-more non-whitespace characters followed by `\s` whitespace, then capture following `(\S+)` one-or-more non-whitespace characters into `$2` (i.e. last name). Note here this just handles the simplest case of a one-name (or initial) firstname, and a one-name lastname.

---

Note: the code above eliminates non-matching lines. If you want to retain non-matching lines, use the following code:

```
~$ raku -ne 'if m/^ (<-[:]>+) \: (\S) \S* \s (\S+)/ {put "$0,{($1,$2).join.lc}"} else {put $_};'  file

#OR 

~$ raku -ne 'm/^ (<-[:]>+) \: (\S) \S* \s (\S+)/ ?? put "$0,{($1,$2).join.lc}" !! put $_;'  file
```

Above `put $_`s the line verbatim if no match (the line is stored in `$_`, which is Perl/Raku's "topic variable"). If you want to blank out these lines, use `"".put` or `put ""`.

https://raku.org